# Java TCP Client doesn't receive messages sent from C# Server

Tags: c#, java, tcp, client-server

I'm writing a tcp server in c# and corresponding client in java. I'm testing the connection on localhost, and the client is able to connect to the server. However, when I'm sending messages, the client never receives them. Using the debugger I've verified that stream.Write(...) is executed. Any idea what the problem could be?

This is the c# server:

```
        TcpClient client = (TcpClient)cl;
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        byte[] msg = new byte[512];
        int bytesRead; 

        while (running)
        {
            while (messages.getCount() > 0)
            {
                String msg = messages.Take();

                if (cmd != null)
                {
                    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg.ToCharArray());

                    try
                    {
                        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                        stream.Flush();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }

            Thread.Sleep(1000); 
        }
```

And the Java client:

```
public void run() 
{
    try 
    {
        socket = new Socket(address, port);
        in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( socket.getInputStream() ));
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        running = true;
    } 
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        running = false; 
    } 

    String data;
    while(running)
    {
        try 
        {
            data = in.readLine();

            if(data != null)
            {
                processData(data);
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

            running = false; 
            break;
        }
    }

    try 
    {
        socket.close();
        socket = null;
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    running = false; 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `BufferedReader.readLine()`. Are your message strings terminated by a CR, LF, or CR/LF?

`readLine` blocks until a line-terminating character is read.